# Creating a ModelBinder to Sanitize user input in HTML format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, factory-method

I have a custom model binder which takes user input in HTML format, sanitize the HTML input by removing any script or XSS threat and returns the sanitized HTML string:

```
public class AllowAndSanitizeHtmlBinder : IModelBinder
{

    private HtmlSanitizer _htmlSanitizer = HtmlSanitizerFactory.CreateInstance();

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var name = bindingContext.ModelName;

        // get the un-validated user input in HTML format
        var unsanitizedMessageHtmlString = request.Unvalidated[name]; 

        // removed script or any XSS threat from user input
        return _htmlSanitizer.Sanitize(unsanitizedMessageHtmlString); 
    }
}
```

I am using [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer) Nuget package to do this. I need to configure this object and tell it to add "nofollow" to all the links.

So I have created `HtmlSanitizerFactory` to do this configuration:

```
public static class HtmlSanitizerFactory
{
    public static HtmlSanitizer CreateInstance()
    {
        var sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
        sanitizer.PostProcessNode += (s, e) =>  (e.Node as IHtmlAnchorElement)?.SetAttribute("rel", "nofollow noreferrer");
        return sanitizer;
    }
}
```

I am not entirely happy with this code. The reason is, in the future, a developer may forget that `HtmlSanitizerFactory` should be used for instantiating `HtmlSanitizer`... so he would create his new `ModelBinder` and initialize the object like:

```
HtmlSanitizer _htmlSanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
```

This would introduce a bug because links won't be converted to "nofollow"

I think DI would have worked much better here, but I don't know how to inject a class into a custom `ModelBinder`

Answer (score 3):

### Developer gone 'rogue'

> *I am not entirely happy with this code. The reason is, in the future, a developer may forget that HtmlSanitizerFactory should be used for
>   instantiating HtmlSanitizer... so he would create his new ModelBinder
>   ..*

For this to happen, a developer has to dive in your code and deliberately change

> ```
> private HtmlSanitizer _htmlSanitizer = HtmlSanitizerFactory.CreateInstance();
> ```

to

```
 private HtmlSanitizer _htmlSanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
```

He would probably have a good reason to. And if not, other developers in the team should review and challenge that change. After all, it's best practice to perform code reviews, typically with *pull requests*.

---

### Test-Driven Development

You have introduced a dependency on a third-party class in your code. Generally, when providing such API code, you would like to reduce the hard dependencies to a minimum. What you could do, is use its interface `IHtmlSanitizer` instead. This allows for white-bow testing such as

```
string unsanitizedMessageHtmlString = ".."; // some input
IHtmlSanitizer sanitizer = Mock<IHtmlSanitizer>(); // using some mock method ..
sanitizer.AssertWasCalled(m => m.Sanitize(unsanitizedMessageHtmlString));
```

You could go a step further and refactor out the third-party dependency entirely by providing your own interface. An adapter class mapping the third-party interface to yours can than be provided in a different library if you wish interop with that API. I am not suggesting this is a must. You should decide which dependencies you want to include in your own API.

#### Regression

> *But it is likely that a year from now, we need to developer a new model binder to sanitize a different HTML input. It is at that point
>   that the developer could forget to initialize the sanitizer using the
>   factory.*

In the comments you stated you are worried for new developers to use that class in a wrong way, possibly introducing bugs. These bugs should become apparent when providing *unit tests*. With white-box tests you can check whether `PostProcessNode` was registered to. And with black-box tests you could easily verify the content of the sanitized string.

It also wouldn't hurt to provide a team Wiki with guidelines, do's and dont's for new developers to get acquainted with the conventions and avoidable regressions.

---

### Dependency Injection

Instead of calling the factory to get an instance of `HtmlSanitizer`, you should use *Dependency Injection*. One way to do so is to have the dependency injected through the constructor.

```
public AllowAndSanitizeHtmlBinder(IHtmlSanitizer htmlSanitizer)
{
    _htmlSanitizer = htmlSanitizer;
}
```

You would typically have an Ioc container where you register the dependencies. I don't know enough about the `IModelBinder`'s lifetime scope, so you may also want to register these to the container.

```
container.RegisterSingleInstance<IHtmlSanitizer>(HtmlSanitizerFactory.CreateInstance());
```

---

### Resource Management

I don't like the third-party class [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer/blob/master/src/HtmlSanitizer/HtmlSanitizer.cs). The events are never cleared and the class does not implement `IDisposable`. It's a memory leak waiting to occur. You need to find a way to dispose these instances yourself and make sure to unsubscribe from:

> ```
>  sanitizer.PostProcessNode += (s, e) =>  (e.Node 
>      as IHtmlAnchorElement)?.SetAttribute("red", "nofollow noreferrer");
> ```